# How compiling simple example C using llvm

Tags: makefile, llvm

Where is my mistake? How is good compiling?

```
llvm-gcc p.c -S -emit-llvm
lli p.s
lli: p.s:1:2: error: expected top-level entity
        .file   "p.c"
        ^
```

simple code

```
cat p.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those flags will produce a file name `p.ll` not `p.s`. Therefore:

```
[2:24pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] llvm-gcc p.c -S -emit-llvm
[2:25pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ~/Homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/lli p.ll
Hello World!
```